# Fallo socket ESP32 (Arduino) - App (Android Studio)

Tags: android, socket, arduino, tcpip, cliente

Estoy intentando establecer un socket entre una aplicación Android (desarrollada en Android Studio) y un módulo ESP32 (programado con Arduino), siendo este último el servidor. Este socket deberá establecerse vía WiFi, utilizando el protocolo TCP/IP, y tanto el smartphone en el que pruebo la app como el módulo ESP32 están conectados a la misma red de área local. Tras consultar distintos ejemplos, conseguí escribir ambos códigos.

El problema es que no se establece el socket por alguna razón. He probado a escribir en un TextView de la app, dentro de la AsyncTask encargada de establecer la conexión (Comm), un mensaje indicador de que efectivamente se ha alcanzado el punto en el que se establece dicho enlace. Sin embargo, este mensaje solo me aparece cuando ordeno que se escriba antes del establecimiento del socket; si lo pongo después, no llega a aparecer. Esto me hace pensar que el socket no termina de establecerse pero tampoco da error, sino que se mantiene en un intento de conexión permanente (aunque en realidad soy novato, no tengo mucha idea de qué estará pasando).

Este es el código Java en Android Studio (cliente), y en el que creo que está el fallo:

```
package com.example.controlluz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button button;
    private boolean on;

    String estado = "0";

    private Toast toast;
    public TextView textview;
    Comm comm;

    //Inicializo variables y establezco socket
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textview.setText("");

        //mTCPCliente = null;

        comm = new Comm();
        comm.execute(estado);
 
    }
 

    //Cuando pulso el botón se enciende o se apaga, en función de su estado anterior
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        //I change button's background
        if (!on) {
            button.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.encendido));
            on = true;
            estado = "1";
        } else {
            button.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.apagado));
            on = false;
            estado = "0";
        }
    }

 

    public class Comm extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> {

        String ip;
        int puerto;

        Comm() {
            ip = "192.168.1.88";
            puerto = 8888;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... estado) {

            Socket sk = null;
            PrintWriter salida = null;
            BufferedReader entrada = null;
 

            try {
                sk = new Socket(ip, puerto);
                textview.setText("Hola?????");
                salida = new PrintWriter(sk.getOutputStream(), true);
                entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
                salida.println(estado[0]);
                //lectura = in.readLine();
                salida.close();
                entrada.close();
                sk.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 
            return null;
        }
 
    }
 
}
```

En el IDE de Arduino veo que se conecta el módulo a la red y que la dirección IP es la deseada, pero en ningún momento aparece el mensaje que indica que hay un cliente conectado (lógicamente).

Este es el código en Arduino (servidor):

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "PASCAL";                                  //NOMBRE ROUTER
const char* password = "1473DE3054C57C4867EB";                //CONTRASEÑA

IPAddress ip(192,168,1,88);                                   //DIRECCIÓN IP ESP8266
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);                               //PUERTA DE ENLACE
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);                              //MÁSCARA DE RED
WiFiServer wifiServer(8888);                                  //PUERTO DE ESCUCHA DEL SERVIDOR
WiFiClient client;
int relayPin = 23;                                            //PIN DEL RELÉ EN EL MÓDULO
char c;

                        
 

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  delay(500);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);                                  //CONEXIÓN WIFI A ROUTER
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);                           //CONFIGURACIÓN DE IP ESTÁTICA
  
  int n;
  for (n = 0; n < 30 && WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED; n++ ) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting...");
  }
  if(n==30){
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("La conexión no ha podido establecerse");
  }else{
    Serial.print("Connected to WiFi. IP:");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }


 
  
  wifiServer.begin();                                         //ESTABLECER ESP8266 COMO SERVIDOR
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);                                  //CONFIGURACIÓN DEL PIN DEL RELÉ COMO PIN DE SALIDA
  digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);                                //Se inicializa a 0 lógico, la luz permanece apagada cuando se arranca el módulo

}

void loop() {
  client = wifiServer.available();

  if(client){
    Serial.println("Client connected");
    Serial.print("Client connected with IP:");
    Serial.println(client.remoteIP());
 
    while( client.connected()){

        while (client.available()>0) {
          c = client.read();
          Serial.println(c);

          switch (c){
            case '1':
              digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
              break;
            case '0':
              digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
              break;
          }
        }
        delay(10);
    }
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  }
   
}
```

Cualquier tipo de información me vendrá bien seguro.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Qué valor tiene `sk` cuando creas `new Socket`?

Comment: No sé cómo puedo mirar eso

Comment: Ejecutando en modo `debug` en el Android Studio.

Comment: Vale, lo he hecho y veo que sk = null; haciendo break en la línea en la que se supone que se establece

Comment: Lo hago en la siguiente y obtengo que `sk={Socket@7415}"Socket[address=/192.168.1.88,port=8888,localPort=49031]`

Comment: No utilizas `DataOutputStream`? te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176393/android-java-sockets-delay-in-sending-data

Comment: Resulta que funciona con esos códigos, no sé qué pudo fallar antes. Gracias en cualquier caso, `@Bicho`. Si alguien quiere hacer algo similar, aquí tiene la base.

Comment: perdón por no responder pero lo pudiste solucionar? Estoy tratando de hacer algo parecido y tampoco logro conexión, yo programo el esp32 en micropython pero supongo q el error está en la app puesto q otra app de comunicación tcp/ip si puede establecer comunicación con el servidor.

Comment: @AlejandroSabogal